# Is there a way to add perspective to mapbox GL markers?

Tags: mapbox, mapbox-gl, mapbox-gl-js, mapbox-marker

I have a map click function that draws a ripple (animated gif) on the ground. Because it's possible to tilt the camera, the ripple effect only looks right from the top down perspective.
Is there a way of adding a perspective element to a marker which can be updated or set based on the current map tilt?

This is my ground hit code.

```
map.on('click', function (e) {

    groundHit = document.createElement('div');
    groundHit.classList.add('groundHit');
    groundHit.style.backgroundImage = 'url(img/ripple.gif)';
    groundHit.style.width = '40px';
    groundHit.style.height = '40px';
    groundHit.style.perspective = '100px';

    var newGroundHit = new mapboxgl.Marker(groundHit, {
            offset: [-20, -20]
        })
        .setLngLat(e.lngLat)
        .addTo(map);

        setInterval(function() {
            newGroundHit.remove();
        }, 350);

});
```

Answer (score 1):

We do not currently support this feature. Sorry!